# Android TLSv1.2 handshake_failure

Tags: java, android, ssl

The Android platform is 5.0.2.

I am unable to connect from a desktop application to an android app using TLSv1.2, though I am able to do the reverse. The application works for desktop <-> desktop, but when it comes to desktop -> android, the handshake fails.

When using debug on the desktop application, I see he following debug lines:

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=TestRoot
  Issuer:  CN=TestRoot
  Algorithm: RSA;

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=TestSigner
  Issuer:  CN=TestRoot
  Algorithm: RSA;

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1418912953 bytes = { 5, 193, 122, 165, 40, 110, 181, 22, 3, 133, 209, 175, 31, 56, 29, 235, 82, 140, 141, 158, 205, 97, 136, 187, 230, 198, 241, 112 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
Thread-46, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 249
Thread-24, handling exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Thread-46, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 81
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 905935073 bytes = { 70, 15, 125, 227, 193, 86, 235, 186, 12, 219, 240, 109, 180, 181, 203, 28, 6, 189, 236, 176, 45, 86, 2, 90, 24, 207, 44, 91 }
Session ID:  {250, 151, 123, 72, 39, 220, 84, 212, 89, 136, 34, 51, 253, 53, 165, 192, 120, 214, 113, 233, 49, 31, 13, 112, 106, 18, 124, 146, 229, 185, 154, 11}
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-8, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
** TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Thread-46, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 2687
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=test
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 4096 bits
  modulus: ...
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Jul 01 21:02:36 SGT 2015,
               To: Fri Jul 01 21:02:36 SGT 2016]
  Issuer: CN=TestSigner
  SerialNumber: [    093fc5c0 639f34bb]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
  Key_Agreement
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
  ...
]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=TestSigner
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 15360 bits
  modulus: ...
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sun Aug 03 22:55:15 SGT 2014,
               To: Fri Aug 03 22:55:15 SGT 2114]
  Issuer: CN=TestRoot
  SerialNumber: [    494777f7 98569fd6]

Certificate Extensions: 2
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
  Key_Agreement
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  RFC822Name: test@test.com
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
  ...
]
Thread-46, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 910
*** Diffie-Hellman ServerKeyExchange
DH Modulus:  { 166, 241, 11, 8, 243, 4, 185, 96, 190, 71, 193, 62, 163, 205, 160, 207, 181, 199, 71, 132, 191, 101, 216, 140, 218, 160, 84, 141, 28, 116, 171, 120, 30, 85, 172, 246, 166, 127, 12, 76, 118, 210, 152, 43, 171, 231, 2, 45, 172, 240, 255, 37, 156, 58, 172, 186, 146, 122, 216, 37, 171, 152, 228, 88, 69, 102, 126, 153, 188, 137, 22, 107, 236, 213, 243, 162, 19, 209, 249, 145, 164, 106, 188, 75, 35, 53, 247, 22, 116, 79, 98, 218, 16, 40, 33, 67, 238, 131, 106, 63, 196, 90, 73, 42, 130, 217, 72, 180, 7, 198, 27, 79, 156, 120, 48, 166, 247, 3, 119, 96, 168, 78, 187, 171, 121, 81, 205, 205 }
DH Base:  { 106, 135, 220, 55, 213, 177, 10, 221, 116, 124, 79, 217, 180, 115, 28, 65, 155, 45, 84, 89, 64, 79, 163, 4, 40, 141, 253, 113, 170, 157, 250, 52, 23, 204, 129, 202, 110, 76, 204, 85, 162, 81, 6, 233, 250, 234, 140, 8, 52, 8, 80, 135, 152, 37, 154, 73, 56, 218, 46, 166, 112, 45, 242, 23, 175, 254, 74, 220, 68, 175, 16, 243, 191, 81, 108, 10, 3, 130, 47, 243, 253, 91, 231, 189, 61, 12, 207, 229, 83, 168, 152, 241, 115, 251, 68, 153, 103, 63, 208, 54, 221, 131, 194, 202, 182, 67, 8, 21, 132, 110, 7, 136, 75, 108, 17, 244, 113, 188, 33, 136, 45, 19, 102, 10, 114, 80, 84, 128 }
Server DH Public Key:  { 105, 32, 79, 179, 156, 35, 191, 64, 76, 243, 253, 64, 144, 103, 176, 207, 202, 131, 230, 244, 70, 233, 209, 197, 136, 48, 104, 125, 175, 230, 189, 158, 207, 57, 154, 32, 243, 130, 180, 140, 139, 244, 121, 37, 47, 204, 216, 194, 112, 132, 31, 236, 181, 65, 106, 32, 13, 94, 146, 146, 100, 203, 201, 242, 246, 134, 235, 95, 157, 28, 253, 94, 116, 144, 17, 8, 20, 65, 24, 161, 30, 132, 138, 221, 252, 42, 106, 53, 246, 46, 107, 204, 200, 8, 145, 126, 86, 114, 187, 203, 195, 223, 194, 246, 244, 90, 174, 138, 41, 219, 122, 99, 153, 62, 128, 44, 4, 86, 97, 241, 240, 154, 217, 237, 16, 10, 56, 51 }
Anonymous
Thread-46, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 192
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: Fixed DH (RSA sig), Fixed DH (DSS sig), RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x4, signature:0x2), SHA256withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x3, signature:0x2), SHA224withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=TestRoot>
<CN=TestRoot>
*** ServerHelloDone
ssl: Ignoring alias test2: issuers do not match
*** Certificate chain
ssl: KeyMgr: no matching key found
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, DH
DH Public key:  { 52, 163, 115, 254, 1, 232, 205, 222, 138, 84, 34, 200, 12, 63, 80, 16, 172, 212, 136, 187, 194, 86, 100, 45, 156, 223, 34, 79, 124, 42, 51, 178, 148, 160, 183, 161, 62, 253, 144, 56, 112, 210, 99, 200, 52, 112, 228, 168, 194, 246, 81, 114, 21, 209, 185, 47, 166, 216, 30, 72, 14, 230, 196, 162, 68, 220, 210, 182, 223, 104, 116, 53, 13, 117, 116, 251, 128, 230, 173, 167, 34, 17, 135, 100, 154, 246, 143, 213, 9, 77, 84, 105, 97, 78, 86, 201, 155, 109, 173, 48, 29, 115, 67, 34, 16, 103, 40, 92, 224, 62, 215, 50, 172, 60, 148, 133, 248, 91, 44, 155, 141, 129, 221, 13, 231, 137, 162, 238 }
Thread-46, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 141
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
...
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
...
Server Nonce:
...
Master Secret:
...
Client MAC write Secret:
...
Server MAC write Secret:
...
Client write key:
...
Server write key:
...
... no IV derived for this protocol
Thread-46, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 48, 1, 70, 112, 37, 1, 12, 205, 242, 80, 92, 219 }
***
Thread-46, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
Thread-46, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Thread-46, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-8, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
Thread-46, called closeSocket()
Thread-46, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1991)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1104)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you got the solution? Do you know the possiblity?

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the debug flag

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake,failure
```

I am guessing that you are likely hitting the key strength issue which is more if you have higher number of bits. You need to download ***Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files*** which enables the key strength of higher bits.

[Handling and Identifying SSL Handshake failures.](http://ramannanda.blogspot.in/2015/03/handling-and-identifying-ssl-handshake.html)

Comment: I already have the JCE patched. Can you tell me what is the maximum RSA key strength without the JCE patch, please?

Comment: It would depend i guess. But generally 256 bits. The issue is your desktop does not have unlimited strength policy installed. So, it can only communicate through 128 bit keys, Hence handshake is failing.

Comment: I have edited the debug statements in the original post. Please have a look, thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you add the debug flag for ssl? As shown as the logs aren't detailed.

Comment: Pardon me, I thought only the part where it says handshake_failure would suffice. I have edited in the full log (with some info taken out). Please take a look, thank you.

Comment: You need to either drop the use of TLSV1.2 or enable that in your client JDK.   java -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" .See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html.

Comment: I have dropped the Android server to TLSv1.1 even though 5.0.2 is supposed to support TLSv1.2 by default, and put the statement `System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");` at the start of the desktop application, however, the handshake_failure still persists.